# Makefile - Why is the read command not reading the user input?

Tags: bash, makefile, shell

I have the following code inside a Makefile:

```
# Root Path
echo "What is the root directory of your webserver? Eg. ~/Server/htdocs" ;
read root_path ;
echo $root_path ;
if [ ! -d $root_path ] ; then \
    echo "Error: Could not find that location!" ; exit 1 ; \
fi
```

However when typing anything (eg. "asd") this is what gets returned:

```
What is the root directory of your webserver? Eg. ~/Server/htdocs

asd
oot_path
Error: Could not find that location!
```

When what I would expect to see would be:

```
What is the root directory of your webserver? Eg. ~/Server/htdocs

asd
asd
Error: Could not find that location!
```

How do I fix this???

Comment: Voting for this question because I think it probably comes up repeatedly, but see what Greg, John and Daenyth say about actually doing this: *the axe murder who next maintains your code will **not** like it.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The immediate problem is that Make itself interprets the `$` differently than the shell does. Try:

```
    echo "What is the root directory of your webserver? Eg. ~/Server/htdocs"; \
    read root_path; \
    echo $$root_path
```

The double `$$` escapes the `$` for Make, so it passes the single `$` through to the shell. Note also that you will need to use `\` line continuations so that the whole sequence is executed as one shell script, otherwise Make will spawn a *new* shell for each line. That means that anything you `read` will disappear as soon as its shell exits.

I would also say that in general, prompting for interactive input from a Makefile is uncommon. You might be better off using a command line switch to indicate the web server root directory.

Comment: Seconding the "prompting for interactive input is uncommon" idea. You don't want to have to answer a prompt every time you type `make`.

Comment: I'd s/uncommon/an abomination/. That's what `configure` scripts and make variables are for

Comment: Thanks! I always thought Makefiles were just glorified shell scripts, but this definitely shows otherwise. Will definitely have to reconsider my use cases with them. @Daenyth, what do you mean by configure scripts? Are they something special???

Comment: @balupton: Plain make has some trouble dealing with things that change across platforms and installations. Especially the original `make` which was rather less powerful than GNU make. A convention arose to write configure scripts which would handle the platform specific setup. That tools for writing those files developed. You can look at `autoconf`, if you want, but it is widely considered a nightmare. If you have only a few targets and/or a few platform specific configuration, there are other ways of dealing with these issues.

Comment: Cool thanks. I've moved it into a php installer script that runs on the command line - eventually will have a webpage interface. As it is for configuring a web application. Autoconf seems too out there for this.

Answer (score 7):

Using .ONESHELL makes multiline commands easier to read then using ';' and '\' to separate lines:

```
.ONESHELL:
my-target:
  echo "What is the root directory of your webserver? Eg. ~/Server/htdocs"
  read root_path
  echo $$root_path
```

I don't have enough karma to post comments, therefore an answer (which should've been a comment to the accepted answer):