# How to read just a single character in Makefile

Tags: input, makefile, gnu-make

In a Makefile, reading user input terminated by `<ENTER>` can be implemented by using (the shell function) `read`. On the shell (bash), reading a single character can be done with `read -n 1`. However, I was surprised that `read -n 1` didn't seem to work with GNU Make 4.2.1. Do I miss some escaping here?

Bash:

```
$> echo x | read -n 1 mychar; echo 'you typed '$mychar 
you typed x
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    read -n 1 mychar; echo 'you typed '$$mychar
```

Make:

```
$> echo x | make
read -n 1 mychar; echo 'you typed '$mychar
/bin/sh: 1: read: Illegal option -n
```

Does make provide its own version of `read` ?

System: GNU Make 4.2.1, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

PS: I am aware that user interaction is considered bad style, and it clearly should not be used in configuration workflows. However, it comes in quite handy for targets associated with pruning, resetting or deleting data (e.g., `make clear`). And asking for `y/N` confirmation gives you a chance to tell your users what it will take them to rebuild what they are going to remove.

PPS: I know that the regular `read` gives you almost the same functionality, except that you need to hit `<ENTER>`. This question about getting a better understanding for the relationship between make and its shell enviroment.

NB: This problem is different from [Makefile - Why is the read command not reading the user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743793/makefile-why-is-the-read-command-not-reading-the-user-input). They just didn't properly escape the variable.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a change of shell type that's the problem rather than `make`?  Please edit your question to show the output of `/bin/sh --version` .

Comment: Thank you, the comment led me to https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash which gives the answer. I wasn't aware of the shift of `/bin/sh` from bash to dash, just returning to Linux after a long period of using other OSes ;) BTW: `/bin/sh --version` fails (for the dash).

Comment: In order to read a single character, one needs to set the `$SHELL` variable in the Makefile to a shell that can, e.g., `@SHELL=/bin/bash`, cf. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Comment: The very first phrase of the question is an incorrect assumption, which led to the entire question. `make` doesn't have an input functions (maybe Guile does), it runs `$SHELL` for each single command in its targets. I suggest to somehow correct the first sentence.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: Right. But rephrasing basically means to put the answer into the question. Can I suggest you just write your second sentence onwards into an answer? I could do that myself, now that you and G.M. pointed me to the right direction, but I'm not feeling I should take credit for that ;)